# Hadoop 2.4 cannot launch job on aws s3n

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3

I deployed Hadoop 2.4 on AWS EC2 using S3 native file system as a replacement of HDFS. I tried several example apps, all gave me the following stack tracing msgs (an older thread on Jul 24 hang there w/o being resolved... So I attach the DEBUG info here...):

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.jar wordcount s3n://mybkt/wc/ s3n://mybkt/out

14/08/12 21:57:35 DEBUG util.Shell: setsid exited with exit code 0
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[GetGroups], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG util.KerberosName: Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.Groups:  Creating new Groups object
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: java.library.path=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.4.0/lib
14/08/12 21:57:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Falling back to shell based
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: ubuntu
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: s3service.https-only=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: storage-service.internal-error-retry-max=5
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: http.connection-manager.factory-class-name=org.jets3t.service.utils.RestUtils$ConnManagerFactory
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.connection-timeout-ms=60000
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.socket-timeout-ms=60000
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.stale-checking-enabled=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.useragent=null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG utils.RestUtils: Setting user agent string: JetS3t/0.9.0 (Linux/3.13.0-29-generic; amd64; en; JVM 1.7.0_55)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: http.protocol.expect-continue=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.connection-manager-timeout=0
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.retry-max=5
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.proxy-autodetect=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: About to attempt auto proxy detection under Java version:1.7.0_55-b14
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: Sun Plugin reported java version not 1.3.X, 1.4.X, 1.5.X or 1.6.X - trying failover detection...
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: Using failover proxy detection...
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: Plugin Proxy Config List Property:null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: No configured plugin proxy list
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: s3service.default-storage-class=null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: s3service.server-side-encryption=null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: http.connection-manager.factory-class-name=org.jets3t.service.utils.RestUtils$ConnManagerFactory
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.connection-timeout-ms=60000
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.socket-timeout-ms=60000
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.stale-checking-enabled=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.useragent=null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG utils.RestUtils: Setting user agent string: JetS3t/0.9.0 (Linux/3.13.0-29-generic; amd64; en; JVM 1.7.0_55)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: http.protocol.expect-continue=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.connection-manager-timeout=0
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.retry-max=5
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.proxy-autodetect=true
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: About to attempt auto proxy detection under Java version:1.7.0_55-b14
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: Sun Plugin reported java version not 1.3.X, 1.4.X, 1.5.X or 1.6.X - trying failover detection...
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: Using failover proxy detection...
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: Plugin Proxy Config List Property:null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG proxy.PluginProxyUtil: No configured plugin proxy list
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: devpay.user-token=null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: devpay.product-token=null
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.Jets3tProperties: httpclient.requester-pays-buckets-enabled=false
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1250)
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG mapreduce.Cluster: Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.AbstractService: Service: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate entered state INITED
14/08/12 21:57:36 DEBUG service.AbstractService: Service: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl entered state INITED
14/08/12 21:57:37 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /172.31.20.187:8032
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.getProxy(RMProxy.java:130)
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG ipc.YarnRPC: Creating YarnRPC for org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC: Creating a HadoopYarnProtoRpc proxy for protocol interface org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocol
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG ipc.Server: rpcKind=RPC_PROTOCOL_BUFFER, rpcRequestWrapperClass=class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$RpcRequestWrapper, rpcInvoker=org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker@7d66036e
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG ipc.Client: getting client out of cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@71cebfd2
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl is started
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate is started
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:330)
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedActionException as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3n
14/08/12 21:57:37 INFO mapreduce.Cluster: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider due to error: Error in instantiating YarnClient
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG mapreduce.Cluster: Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG mapreduce.Cluster: Cannot pick org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider - returned null protocol
14/08/12 21:57:37 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedActionException as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1251)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Here are my config files:

yarn-site.xml:

```
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>172.31.20.187:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>172.31.20.187:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>172.31.20.187:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>/home/ubuntu/hdfs/tmp</value>
    </property>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
        <value>640</value>
        <description>Larger resource limit for maps.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx768m</value>
        <description>Heap-size for child jvms of maps.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
        <value>640</value>
        <description>Larger resource limit for reduces.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx768m</value>
        <description>Heap-size for child jvms of reduces.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
        <value>172.31.20.187:8021</value>
    </property>
```

I also followed this link for configuration of AWS S3's access control (core-site.xml):
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3

core-site.xml:

```
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>s3n://mybkt</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
        <value>131072</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
        <value>123</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
        <value>456</value>
    </property>
```

I tried Hadoop v1 as well and turns out Hadoop1 on s3n file system works. But it seems it doesn't work for Hadoop v2.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think using s3 or any other file-system implementation as an replacement for HDFS/Namenode isn't possible so straightforward.
Tried the same thing with the Tachyon filesystem and failed, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tachyon-users/u4OoBekGigA

Think other folks got it to work by:

- adding AbstractFileSystem implementation
- patching Hadoop to not check permissions of staging artifacts

So bottom-line, you can use s3 for reading the input and writing the output of a job but using it as an HDFS replacement for the execution-metadata layer isn't supported out of the box!